# How can I call controller/method inside button onclick?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to call a controller with method onclick. I solved this, but I want to find a solution for this.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="<?php  ?>">Sign Up</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use like this,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
        onclick="<?php echo base_url()?>controller/function">Sign Up</button>
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url("controller/fun_name");?>'">Sign Up</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 <?php echo base_url(); ?> "controller/function"
```

this should do it

Answer (score 0):

calling controller in button

Ex.

controller name is "**home**"

function name is "**insert**"

```
<form action="home/insert" method="POST">
//add codes here
</form>
```

here useful links ->
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag like this. This will redirect you to another page on click.

```
<?=   anchor("controllerclassname/method",'Sign Up',['class'=>'btn btn-success float-left']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="window.location='<?= base_url(); ?>/Admin/admin_profile'"
```

this one will work else check your base URL `App/config/App.php`  in Codeigniter 4

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="<?= base_url('controller/method')  ?>">Sign Up</button>
```

First you have to add **base_url** in config.php
then you can call your controller

and  are same